# How to convert html content in to one string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

let html="

Some data
 some more data 
with
 some other data
need to convert into string

"

I want it should be become a single string like
str="Some data, some more data, some other data, need to convert into string";

This I need in Reactjs functionality.

In comment section I have shared the details more

Comment: `<p>Some data
<span> some more data </span> 
with 
<a> some other data</a> 
need to convert into string
</p>`

I want it should be become a single string like
str="Some data, some more data, some other data, need to convert onto string";

This I need in Reactjs functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to replace the HTML tags, something like:

```js
const getNormalisedString = (str) => (str ?? '').replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

const input = "<p>Some data <span> some more data </span>  with  <a> some other data</a>  need to convert into string </p>";

console.log(getNormalisedString(input));
```

But I would recommend using a parser, and if that is not available then some library to sanitize your HTML string like [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html)